# SKView Resizing To Fit 3.5in Screen Correctly?

Tags: uiview, sprite-kit, autoresize, skscene, skview

I have an SKView that looks great both on a 4in and 3.5in device. The problem is that on the 3.5in device, the bottom part of the view gets cut off (As if attached to the top). How can I have the top (sky) cut off instead? So that the bottom of the SKView is at the bottom of the 3.5in screen's frame.

Thanks!

Update: Here's a screenshot to better explain the situation.

[image]

In other words on a 3.5in device the bottom is getting cropped off, but I'd rather have the top cropped off.

Comment: Could you give us a snapshot of what you want to do?

Comment: Sure! Just updated my answer.

Comment: That's great. How are you setting the texture for the background on the scene?

Comment: I believe you can "fix" that by changing the scene's anchorPoint to {1, 0} and adjusting the position of other nodes accordingly. Or you can add an additional SKNode parent where you add all nodes that used to be children of the scene, and offset that node accordingly so that you don't need to modify all the node's positions.